# Update Sharepoint metadata using R

Tags: r, sharepoint, metadata, httr, openxlsx

I have an Excel file that I am autopopulating using R and then uploading to my SharePoint site using the "openxlsx" package. After saving this item to SharePoint, I want to set some of the columns of metadata that are associated with my library. I am not really sure if this is possible, and if it is, I have been unable to find anything on Google about it. Has anyone done this before?

Thanks!

To make it easier, here is the code I want to replicate in R but it keeps throwing a "Bad error"

```
headers_update_metadata ={
    "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
    'Authorization': 'Bearer '+access_token,
    "X-HTTP-Method":"MERGE",
    "If-Match": "*",
    'Content-Type': 'application/json;odata=verbose',
    'Connection':'keep-alive',
}


body = { '__metadata': { 'type': 'SP.Data.Shared_x0020_DocumentsItem' }, 'Author': authorName}

r = requests.post(update_file_url, json=body, headers=headers_update_metadata)
```

Comment: I have the same question. Trying to change metadata of pdf file using sharepoint REST API and R. Anyone solve it yet?